# How to make a TextView Show in Over of Screen

Tags: android, textview

I have 3 Text view that String of the Texts will changes in java code every some seconds and some times that the String is Long, my text view make the text to show in 2 lines but i dont want this happen!!
i want to text show in 1 line (with no changing of size) Even Out Of Screen! no matter user see that or not!
TIA!:D

[image]

Comment: set this android:singleLine="true" properties to your TextView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use that line

```
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
android:ellipsize="end" 
android:maxLines="1"
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure you can go out of the sreen but add this to your XML

```
android:singleLine=true
```

Say if it works !

Answer (score 1):

```
android:singleLine="true"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Here is the solution 


    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="Approximation" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="Internationalssssssssssssssss" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="Applicationssssssssssssssssssssssss" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```